# Indoor vs outdoor fire safety training for kids

Tags: fireplace, fire-extinguisher

I want to train my two sons on how to use a fire extinguisher.

It's pretty wet this time of year in the northwest, so I was considering making a fire in our fireplace inside, and having them take turns using the extinguisher.... But could this cause a big mess inside? Or lots of smoke? etc...

If the indoor solution is no good, I think I'll have to wait for a dry night to dig a hole and make a fire in the yard (or buy a metal platform for fires).

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whilst learning how to be proficient with a fire extinguisher is a good thing doing it inside in a fireplace is pretty foolhardy thing to do. There is danger of the fire bursting out of the fireplace, getting icky chemicals all over the place and the flat out mess of it all.

My suggestion regarding the fire place is to teach your youngsters the proper care, usage and cautions of using the fire place in the correct and safe way.

For the basic fire safety training (including use of the fire extinguisher) I think you should check with your local fire department or community fire safety officials to see if they offer anything in the way of training, classes or workshops. If you attended these with your youngsters and participated the same as they would it would likely have a more lasting impression on them than something ad hoc that you could fire up in your back yard.

Comment: However I imagine that most advice from the fire department will boil down to "don't be a hero, evacuate and call 911".